# Inheriting a class with references in the constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am using Arduino and i try to create a custom Serial Class that filters out special data. Therefore i want to inherit the HardwareSerial to access its protected RX buffer.

I can imagine of three solutions:
Inherit the class to access this buffer

Create an instance of this class in my class but then i dont know how to access the protected buffer

Copy the whole class or just inherit a few functions to modify all functions. might be the best solution.

What is working:

```
.h:
extern HardwareSerial Serialk;
.cpp:
HardwareSerial Serialk(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L, &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
Serialk._tx_udr_empty_irq();
```

But i cannot inherit the class like this:

```
class CUSB : public HardwareSerial (&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR){
[..] }
```

This throws errors like this:

> D:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\USB/USB.h:36:50: error: invalid type in declaration before ',' token
>    class CUSB : public HardwareSerial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR){
>                                                     ^
>   D:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\USB/USB.h:36:50: error: 'UBRRL' declared as reference but not initialized
>   D:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\USB/USB.h:36:53: error: 'UCSRA' declared as reference but not initialized
>    class CUSB : public HardwareSerial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to instance the HardwareSerial object where you declare it as a base class. This should be done in the constructor of your own object.

```
class CUSB : public HardwareSerial {

    // Constructor method
    CUSB() : HardWareserial( /* your variables you wish to pass on to base class. */ ) {
        /* Initialize your own class. */
    }

    [..]
};
```

Comment: Awesome(working)! Is there also a way to overwrite the virtual functions but still use it as another instance? So i can do USB.Serial.print();? Do i have to create another class like CUSBSerial and create an instance in my CUSB class or is there a simpler way?

Comment: If you mean calling the base's implementation of an overridden virtual method, you can do that: `class CUSB : public HardwareSerial { virtual void foo() override { HardwareSerial::foo(); } };`. You'll have to clarify if you meant something else.